# TYPO3 RouteEnhancer for extension web2pdf

Tags: routes, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

I am trying to set up a RouteEnhacer for the TYPO3 extension web2pdf to rewrite URLs like [https://example.com/subpage/?tx_web2pdf_pi1[action]=generatePdfLink&tx_web2pdf_pi1[argument]=printPage&tx_web2pdf_pi1[controller]=Pdf&cHash=123456789](https://example.com/subpage/?tx_web2pdf_pi1%5Baction%5D=generatePdfLink&tx_web2pdf_pi1%5Bargument%5D=printPage&tx_web2pdf_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Pdf&cHash=123456789) to https://example.com/subpage/pdf/.

By using …

```
routeEnhancers:
  Web2pdf:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/pdf/{argument}'
    namespace: 'tx_web2pdf_pi1'
    aspects:
      argument:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          1: printPage
```

… I already got the URLs a bit shorter:

[https://example.com/subpage/pdf/1/?tx_web2pdf_pi1[action]=generatePdfLink&tx_web2pdf_pi1[controller]=Pdf&cHash=123456789](https://example.com/subpage/pdf/1/?tx_web2pdf_pi1%5Baction%5D=generatePdfLink&tx_web2pdf_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Pdf&cHash=123456789)

Can the routing be optimized further so that I get the desired short URL?

I suspect an Extbase route enhancer would be better, but my attempts have all failed and no rewriting has taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there is no need to map **controller** and **action**, as these are default arguments, automatically handled with a proper configured enhancer. The only (non-standard / custom) argument which needs to be mapped is **tx_web2pdf_pi1[argument]**.

Here is the extbase route enhancer, which generates /your/subpage/pdf:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Pdf:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Web2pdf
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{your_argument_replacement}'
        _controller: 'Pdf::generatePdfLink'
        _arguments:
          your_argument_replacement: 'argument'
    aspects:
      argument:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          pdf: 'printPage'
```

Tested with the following link, rendered by fluid viewhelper:

```
<f:link.action action="generatePdfLink"
                       controller="Pdf"
                       extensionName="Web2pdf"
                       arguments="{argument:'printPage'}">PDF</f:link.action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is already pretty close. The only thing you need to do is expand it to all the aspects of the query.

The query in question contains 3 different aspects (hash is exempt from this) we need to substitute:

```
 1. tx_web2pdf_pi1[argument] (you already configured this one)
 2. tx_web2pdf_pi1[action]
 3. tx_web2pdf_pi1[controller]
```

If we continue like you started we end up with something like this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Web2pdf:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/pdf/{argument}{action}{controller}'
    namespace: 'tx_web2pdf_pi1'
    aspects:
      argument:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          1: printPage
      action:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          2: generatePdfLink
      controller:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          3: Pdf
```

This configuration should generate the following link:

```
https://example.com/subpage/pdf/123
```

To get the desired output we just need to edit the configuration a little bit:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Web2pdf:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/{argument}{action}{controller}'
    namespace: 'tx_web2pdf_pi1'
    aspects:
      argument:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          p: printPage
      action:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          d: generatePdfLink
      controller:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          f: Pdf
```

This should yield your requested link structure:

```
https://example.com/subpage/pdf
```

Comment: Even though I chose Mikel's approach as accepted, it is a very good solution and definitely helps a lot for future problems and understanding of routeEnhancers. Thank you very much.